# SearchManager Android 4.x issue

Tags: android, search

I have been facing a problem using Search Manager with android 4.x sdk version. 
I'm getting ClassCastException at this line

```
String sSearch = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.USER_QUERY);
```

Exception details:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableString cannot be
>   cast to java.lang.String

The issue has been reported at
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22978

Has anyone found a solution or a workaround for this?
Please share!!!
Thank you.

Comment: Used:  

    String sSearch= intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

And issue solved!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this to handle both cases, type "String" or type "SpannableString"

```
String sSearch = intent.getExtras().get(SearchManager.USER_QUERY).toString();
```

Comment: It is incredible to need to use a deprecated method to read the query text (the comment is meant for the Android team, not for Aurélien who saved my butt)